# How to implement a feature like "Device Folders" in the Photos app

Tags: android

Maybe this is due to my ignorance but I just want to have a quick check.

When we open an android Photos app, there is "Device folders" in the navigation drawer menu."
I am high on this feature.

This shows the every images in the smartphone, categorized into its folder location.

Question is,
Does Android SDK supports this feature? (so that all I have to do is use the sdk to open the activity.) or do I have to implement it from the scratch?

What I want to do is.. shows all the pdf files in the phone.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can just query and get the same folders with the MediaStore.

Comment: Pdf files? Is your photo gallery showing them?

Comment: Oops my bad on explaining what I want. The Photos app doesn't show pdf files. I just like the way that Photos app displays the photo files only. Let me make it bit more clear.
Requirement: 
1.When I press a button, I want to show all the pdf files in my smart phone.
2. I am thinking of style that photos app does. (Especially when I press the "Device folders", it shows only photos per each folders.)

Comment: I am keep searching but looks like I have to start from making file explorer.